# Why does this Macro take so long to run?

Tags: excel

My first row of my dataset includes a list of 1's or 0's. I am trying to just hide all rows that contain a zero, then copy the entire sheet to a new sheet. I timed it out and the macro takes around 4 minutes to complete running. Why? Is there a way to re-write this macro to make it quicker? I'm trying to keep this macro universal meaning as long as I have a column with 1's & 0's I can quickly hide large amounts of rows of data, not matter the size. Here is the code...Thank you in advance for any assistance!

```
Sub RemoveLinesWithZero()

For i = 1 To Selection.Rows.Count
    For j = 1 To Selection.Rows.Count
        If Left(Selection.Cells(j, 1), 1) = "0" Then
            Rows(j + 13).EntireRow.Hidden = True
        End If
    Next j
Next i

ActiveSheet.Copy After:=Sheets(Sheets.Count)


End Sub
```

Comment: How big is the sheet?

Comment: Cell-by-cell access is slow. Also the `For i` loop should be removed. You never use `i` inside the loop. Really though, probably should use `Range.AutoFilter`

Comment: The sheet is not that large, almost 700 rows of data spanning across 12 columns

Comment: Am I able to use Range.AutoFilter but use "CurrentRegion" rather that listing a specific range? Because I know my columns headers will shift and the range for the autofilter won't always be consistent